# Stress shift amongst speakers from India

Tags: pronunciation, subcontinental-english, stress

I've noticed that speakers from India shift the stress in some words such as 'adjective', 'sentence' or 'tendency'. They normally stress the second syllable and not the first one as most people are used to. Is there any particular reason for this? Is it a common tendency (never better said) amongst the Indians?

Comment: This undoubtedly is related to which language of the multiple languages spoken in India is their native language, and how that language handles stressed syllables.

Comment: Yes,but I meant amongst English native speakers.

Comment: But they're native Indian Enslish speakers, not American or British English speakers, right? So they'll pick up things like this from other Indian English speakers, whose accent was influenced by Hindu pronunciation.

Comment: Are you **sure** most people pronounce it the way you are used to? Just because the people around you do it differently doesn't mean that's "normal".

Comment: @T.E.D. I think he's describing something that's pretty commonly recognized as part of speaking English with an Indian accent.

Comment: Rules for [stress in Hindi](http://www.learning-hindi.com/post/49768944122/hindi-word-stress): 
"the heaviest syllable in a word is stressed. If two or more syllables are tied then the last of these is stressed — unless this last one is the final syllable in the word in which case you take the heaviest syllable before that." I won't give the exact definition of *"heavy"*, but essentially it means it has longer vowels and/or lots of consonants. In all your examples, the stress is on the heaviest syllable.

Answer (score 2):

My  experience with speakers of various Indian languages (and there are perhaps 50 languages with a million speakers apiece on that Tower-of-Babel of a continent; my sample was fewer than five) is that word-stress is less important than it is in English.  I remember one exchange that went like this:

Me: "Hari, do you pronounce your name HA-ri or ha-RI?"
Hari: *(blankly)* "It's pronounced 'Hari'."

Contrast that with Vietnamese, where stress and tone are almost everything.  I once confused the name of my tour-guide's friend Bo (middle tone, something like *bought*) with bò (falling tone, a little like *but*, and meaning "cow").  The guide and all her other friends thought that was *hilarious*.  They were still repeating to each other and laughing uproariously when I flew home.  The unfortunate Bo might still called "Cow" to this day.

Comment: As an Indian, normative word stresses are things that simply didn't exist for me till I started hearing about how Indian accents are uniquely incomprehensible. Like https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-not-like-the-Indian-English-accent/answer/CJ-Hardy-2 .

Comment: @MilindR — bizarrely, I had not looked at this entry for four years, until about 10 minutes before you commented on it.

Answer (score 0):

Pronunciation of many words in English vary worldwide.  In English, words often have primary (and secondary) accents on the second (and fourth) syllables.  See "pronunciation" and "computer."  Perhaps Indian pronunciation has applied that construction to these words?  Brits and Americans don't agree on which syllable to stress in "incomparable," for instance.

Comment: It is a mistake to claim that everyone on one side of the Atlantic stresses *incomparable* differently from how everyone on the other side of the Atlantic stresses it.

Comment: That might be a... controversy.  (OK, the joke might work better aloud: it's CONtroversy in the US, conTROversy in Blighty.  And to bring us full circle: *[Blighty](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Blighty)* is a corruption of a Hindu word for village)

Answer (score 0):

If English is my second language, learned from speakers of my native language, the phonology of the native language also determines how my English sounds.  In other words, both sound similar despite the dissimilarity in vocabulary and sentence patterns between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, let's bear in mind that languages with membership in disparate language familiies do not share a common phonemic, syntactic,  and semantic inventories.  To speak a foreign language well, that means being easily intelligible to the native speakers of that language, is to learn to keep the features of one's primary language under lock and key, while employing a consciously acquired speech.

Comment: You should edit this into your original answer rather than adding it as a new answer.